# Transformers pipeline with ray does not work on gpu

Tags: huggingface-transformers, ray

I am following the documentation for offline batch inferencing using huggingface on gpu
https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/data/batch_inference.html#using-gpus-for-inference

I get a warning

> You seem to be using the pipelines sequentially on GPU. In order to maximize efficiency please use a dataset

Any ideas how to use it? I think the data is being sent one by one to the pipeline even if the batch size is > 1